# while loop to check anagrams in python

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, anagram

I have the following exercise:
Two words are anagrams if you can rearrange the letters from one to spell the other.
Write a function called is_anagram that takes two strings and returns True if they are anagrams.

I have developed a function, but it is not working properly and I cannot find out why. Could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much.

```
def isa(s,t):  
    if len(s)!=len(t):  
        print "impossible"  
    if len(s)==len(t):  
        i=0  
        while i<len(s)-1:  
            for i in s:  
                if i in t:  
                    print "yay"  
                print "NO"
```

Comment: You don't seem to be incrementing `i`, which is used in the condition of your `while-loop`. Also, I am confused about the combination of `while` and `for` loops here. Just the `for-loop` would have sufficed.

Comment: Try `def isa(t,s): return sorted(t)==sorted(s)`. This puts the strings in the same order and compares them afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much, Abdou. I have eliminated the while-loop and applied few changes. Now it works. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

def is_anagram(s,t):
    return collections.Counter(s) == collections.Counter(t)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, but is not what I am looking for. I would like to debug the structure I have developed with the while-loop and understand my mistake

Comment: @Ajla The best way for you to do that is to just keep hacking away at it.. always